# Need further explanation of proof: Rudin 11.15

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

**Definition**
Set $A$ is measuarable if one can find collection $M$ of subsets of $A$ s.t.
(1) If $S_1\in M, and \ S_2\in M \ then:$
$\ \ S_1 \cup S_2, S_1-S_2 \in M$
(2) Consider sequence $S_i(i\in \mathbb{N})$ of subsets of A in M then:
$\ \ \cup_{i}{S_i}\in M$
(3) $A\in M$

**Prop**
If for all real a, the set:
$\ \{x|f(x)>a\}$
is assumed measurable then:
$\ \{x|f(x)\geq a\}$
is also measurable

**Proof**
Since we have that:
$\ \{x|f(x)\geq a\}=\cap_{n}{\{x|f(x)> a-\frac{1}{n}\}}$
Thus we can see the assertion is valid.

**Problem**
The proof is rather too short. As what I guess is that the author omitted requisite lemma, in order to save the time.
I think the author omitted the prop that:

If countable number of subsets $A_i$ of measurable set $A$ are all measuarable then intersection of them are also measurable.

Then I tried to prove the omitted part as below:
Out goal is to find the collection $M$ composed of subsets of $\cap A_i$, that satisfies conditions (1),(2),(3).
Define $M$ to be intersection of $M_i$ where for each measurable $A_i$ we are given $M_i$ that satisfies (1),(2),(3). If $S_i (i\in \mathbb{N})$ are taken from M then:
$S_1 \cup S_2, S_1 - S_2, \cap S_i$ are all contained in each $M_i$ thus in $M$.

**Quest**

Is it sound enough? Have I understood the concepts right?
Can I apply the analogous arguments so to conclude that:
**The collection of measurable subsets satisfies (1),(2).**
If (1),(2) holds then prop I tried to give proof just succeeds, but not vice versa, and I can't come up with sufficient $M$
that satisfies $S_1 - S_2$ part of (1).

Comment: I believe you might be a little confused. Read the definition of $\sigma$-ring in 11.1 then look at Thm 11.10 and  Example 11.14.

Comment: Okay, but sounds inaccurate. Def 11.12 assumes $A$ need not be a euclidean and $\mu$ need not be Lesbegue nor regular

Comment: Thus I hardly see connection of 11.14 and setups required in 11.15

Comment: Yes. You are right. Ignore my comment about Thm 11.10 and 11.14. I was thinking about R^n. Nevertheless, since you are interested in general measure space, then you need to know that it comes with a $\sigma$-ring.

Comment: Could you recommend math texts that catches what I overlooked for? I'll be appreciated and right look at it. The way Rudin chap11 maneuvers the theory seems to be old-fashioned for me, but is it really?

Comment: Sorry for taking your time, if you don't feel to, I'll find some

Comment: You have a $\sigma$-ring. If $\{x\mid f(x)>a\}$ are measurable, i.e. belongs in the $\sigma$-ring then the intersection is also inside the $\sigma$-ring. You don't need another textbook for this.

Comment: But if you really want a textbook. Try Bartle https://www.amazon.com/Elements-Integration-Lebesgue-Measure/dp/0471042226/ref=sr_1_1?crid=3NQXYZYRH5HY4&keywords=bartle+integration&qid=1647682618&sprefix=bartle+integration%2Caps%2C90&sr=8-1

Comment: Ah, I think need for clarification. Here, the point what I'm trying to know is : Why is collection of measurable sets* a sigma ring? Not the converse

Comment: Did I misunderstand the def 11.13? Is saying **$\{x|f(x)>a\}$ measurable** implies it is element of some sigma ring of X? And not itself distinctively being a 'measurable space' as given in def 11.12?

Comment: Let $X$ be a set and $M = \{ \{\}, X\}$. It can be check that $M$ is a $\sigma$-ring. Hence $(X, M)$ is called a measurable space (the trivial one). Define the function $m:M\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by $m(\{\}) = 0$ and $m(X) =1$, then it is clear that $m$ is additive. Hence $(X, M, m)$ is a measure space by definition. Elements of M are called measurable sets. Here in this trivial example, there are only two measurable sets.

Comment: Yes. $\{x\mid f(x)>a\}$ measurable means exactly that  it is an element of some $\sigma$-ring of $X$.

Comment: Okay, then the prop was trivial. I got it, thanks for  illumination Jacky Chong have a good day